# Currency masking in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I am trying to format the entry in currency format like 10,000.00 in a ion-input field with the below line of code but while entering the text it shows the output as 10,000.0010000. I have tried almost all of the alternate solutions in online and none of them helped me to overcome this situation. tried ng2-currency-mask and its not working

```
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]= Basic pattern="\d*" name="Basic"
                  #Basic="ngModel" clearInput placeholder="0.00">
                  <div>{{selectedCtcBasic | currency: '₹ '}}</div>
                </ion-input>
                <div class="error-form" *ngIf="Basic.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="Basic.errors.pattern">* Text/symbols not allowed</div>
                </div>
              </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically currency masks and directives are applied to input element, but when you use `<ion-input>`, then you can observe by inspecting element that its not input there's some other tags are also added. So you need to add these type of things on input element as shown below -

```
<ion-item>

  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedCtcBasic" name="Basic"
    #Basic="ngModel" clearInput placeholder="0.00" />

    <div>{{selectedCtcBasic | currency: '₹ '}}</div>

</ion-item>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Kumar - Here's stackbitz URL & You can look into this. It works.
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1cg4x8